# Finding linear transformation $T:V\to W$ with specific spaces

Tags: linear-transformations

I have that

$$V=\mathrm{span} \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 2+x , & 1+x  \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)  \subset  \mathbb{R}2[x]{}
$$
 $$W=\mathrm{span} \left(\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1\\ \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) ,\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0\\ \end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\right)\subset   \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}{}
$$
$\dim V=\dim W=2$.
I need to find a bijective linear transformation $T: V\to W$. I know from a theorem that exist bijective transformation like this because $\dim V=\dim W$ but I'm stuck with how can I calculate its formula. Any directions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Send basis vectors of one space to the basis vectors of the other space. For example, consider the transformation $T$ that does the following:
$$T(2+x)=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \qquad T(1+x)=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then by linearity you can get
$$T(x)=T((2(x+1))-(x+2))=2T(x+1)-T(x+2)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-2&-2\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$T(1)=T((x+2))-(x+1))=T(x+2)-T(x+1)=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
So
$$T(a+bx)=aT(1)+bT(x). \ldots $$

Comment: Thank you, cause the polynomial is of 2 degree, so how can i found T($x^{2}{}$) ? I think I cant multiply by x cause it isn't a scalar. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or I shouldn't find it because the transformation isn't defined for polynomial  of 2nd degree ? cause the space is span of vectors of 1st degree? Please correct me if it's wrong...THANKS!

Comment: @A-H $x^2$ does not lie in $V$ as there exists no $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a(1+x) + b(2+x) = x^2$.